# Minimize a value from a black-box function with multiple variables - Python

Tags: python, pandas, algorithm, optimization, minimization

I have an dataframe of multiple rows with input columns x0, x1...xn, and a column of resulting values y.

```
df = pd.read_csv("data.csv")
results = df['y']
inputs = df.drop('y')
```

I would like to minimize the value of y.  I know there exists a combination of inputs x0->xn that provides a minimum value of y.

The resulting value y comes from a black box, that I cannot connect to via code.

Is there an algorithm that determines best guess of inputs to minimize y?  I would then repeat/converge manually until I reduce y enough to my taste.

The input values must be >= 0, and integers

bad pseudo-code of what I imagine:

```
restrictions = (inputs >= 0 & inputs.astype(int))
result = minimize_function(inputs, results, restrictions)
result.x are new inputs
result.y is predicted result (optional)
```

I checked out scipy.optimize but am not sure how to use if the function is truly unknown.

Thank you!

Comment: Are you open to using machine learning...

Comment: If so [this](https://github.com/jostmey/NakedTensor/blob/master/tensor.py) may be good enough

Comment: Definitely open to ML, haven't used models to go in reverse (predict inputs for a given y).  Not sure I get your TF link, having y=mx+b.